# how to view all thread stack of a running process on aix?

Tags: multithreading, process, stack, state, aix

how to view stack and state of all threads of a running process on AIX machine. 
the command or tool like **pstack** on linux should also help..

i tried **procstack**, but didnt help. it does not show any stack to me. and no error though..

any ideas..?

is procstack require all executables and libraries associated with process compiled with debig info?

thanks.

Comment: How did you use procstack and what was the output?

Comment: procstack PID or procstack -F PID
output is nothing..no error message.. just got to next line...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a script I wrote using dbx to print the stack of all threads of the given process id. Hope this helps, worked like a charm for me on aix

```
if [ $# -ne 1 ]
then
   echo "Usage dbxstack <processid>";
   exit;
fi

rm -rf printthreads.fordbx

echo "thread" >> printthreads.fordbx
echo "detach" >> printthreads.fordbx
echo "quit" >> printthreads.fordbx

dbx -a $1 -c printthreads.fordbx > threads.tempdbx 2>/dev/null
awk '$1 ~ /\$t/ { print $1 }' threads.tempdbx | sed s/\$t//g | sed s/\>//g > threadsids.tempdbx

rm -rf printthreads.fordbx
for i in `cat threadsids.tempdbx`
do
   echo "print \"------------------------\"" >> printthreads.fordbx
   echo "thread current $i" >> printthreads.fordbx
   echo "where" >> printthreads.fordbx
   echo "print \"---------tid $i---------\"" >> printthreads.fordbx
   i=$(( $i+1 ));
   echo $i;
done
echo "detach" >> printthreads.fordbx
echo "quit" >> printthreads.fordbx

dbx -a $1 -c printthreads.fordbx > $1.stacktrace 2> $1.stacktracerr

rm -rf threads.tempdbx threadsids.tempdbx printthreads.fordbx
```

Comment: very interesting. I'll be using this if I ever get back to an AIX environment. You can reduce code significantly, but this looks solid otherwise. I.e. `awk '$1 ~ /\$t/ { gsub(/\$t/,"", $1; gsub(/\>/, "", $1; print $1 }' threads.tempdbx |  > threadsids.tempdbx`. Other simplifications are possible. Good luck to all.